# Different results using cv.glm (in boot package) and train (in caret pakcage)

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I wanted to get the test error using leave one out cross validation of logistic regression model in R.

I did that using two methods. 
 1) using cv.glm in boot package
 2) using caret package

The results and the code using cv.glm as follows,

```
require(ISLR)
require(boot)
require(caret)

str(Smarket)
fit1 <- glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume, 
            family = binomial, data = Smarket)

cv.glm(Smarket,fit1)$delta 


> cv.glm(Smarket,fit1)$delta
[1] 0.2518003 0.2517992
```

So the leave one out crossvalidation error is about 0.25

Then I used the caret package. The results and the code using caret as follows,

```
fitControlcv <- trainControl( method = "LOOCV")
mod_fit <- train(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume,
                 data=Smarket, method="glm", family="binomial",
                 trControl = fitControlcv)

mod_fit


> mod_fit
Generalized Linear Model 

1250 samples
   6 predictor
   2 classes: 'Down', 'Up' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 1249, 1249, 1249, 1249, 1249, 1249, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy  Kappa      
  0.4976    -0.02588095
```

In this case the leave one out cross validation test error rate is about 0.50 (1-0.4976)

What may be the reason that I am getting different answers using different packages ?

Did I do any mistake here ?

It is really appreciate if some one can help me out

Comment: looks like these are different measures; caret imposes a cut-point in calculating accuracy, which I think defaults to 0.5, and cv.glm calculates squared error (mean(obs - pred)^2)

Comment: ... `cv.glm` has a cost function: `cv.glm(Smarket, fit1, cost=function(o, p) mean(o == (p > 0.5)))`